# How to restore bash executable after accidentally deleting it?

Tags: command-line, bash, executable

I accidentally did something wrong; what I meant to do was

```
ln -svf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

But, I mistyped it and it became

```
ln -svf /bin/sh /bin/bash
```

So, `bash` is now a symlink that points to `sh` which is a symlink that points to `dash`. How can I restore my executable `bash`?

Comment: Delete the symlink  and run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash
```

Unless something goes wrong with the pre / post installation scripts, you should be able to reinstall `bash` and to collaterally replace the symlink with the executable. If this doesn't work, try to remove the symlink and try again. This will also upgrade `bash` to the latest version.

Comment: kos, upvoted but you should consider `apt-get install --reinstall bash` rather than simply `install`..as the package is already installed `apt-get` should be trying to upgrade the package to the latest version, if failed then the existing one will remain..so there's a problem with simple `apt-get install bash` IMO..

Comment: @heemayl You're right, I simply didn't think about that. Thanks

Comment: "Try" isn't an answer :)